# Is it possible for two random variables to satisfy this propery?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can we find two random variables such that they have a continuous joint cdf but their difference is a discrete random variable?.

I have tried taking a continuous random variable $X$ . And taking another random variable $Y=X+1$.

Then their difference has a discrete distribution...namely $P(X-Y=-1)=1$ . But how do I show that the joint cdf of $X,Y$ is continuous?.

What is the proper way to construct such an example?

Comment: What is the definition of having a continuous joint distribution? I.e., do you want the joint distribution to be **absolutely continuous** with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: No. I just want that the joint cdf to be a continuous function. That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea works.

If $F$ denotes the CDF of $X$ and $G$ denotes the joint CDF of $(X,Y)$  then:$$G(x,y)=P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=P(X\leq x, X\leq y-1)=P(X\leq\min(x,y-1))=F(\min(x,y-1))$$

Since $F$ is continuous $G$ can be recognized as a continuous function.

Comment: Yeah that is what I wanted to show. I was confused as to show how F can be continuous. But I guess that is trivial right?. I mean if f(x) is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then f(x-1) should be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Sure. What we have here is a composition of $3$ continuous functions: $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y-1)$ and $\min$ and $F$. A composition of continuous functions is continuous.